# How to move XML file data to PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

This is my xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<smslist>
 <sms>
  <cid>FIRSTCID</cid>
  <mid>FIRSTMID</mid>
  <mb>98389923</mb>
 </sms>
 <sms>
  <cid>SECONDCID</cid>
  <mid>SECONDMID</mid>
  <mb>76445645</mb>
 </sms>
...
</smslist>
```

How to push `cid` and `mid` data to php array like `$array = array(("FIRSTCID","FIRSTMID"),("SECONDCID","SECONDMID")...)`

Excuse if this is some duplicate question. :)

Answer (score 1):

> you can try this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($your_xml_string);
$xml_array=[];
foreach ($xml->smslist->sms as $sms) {
    $xml_array[]=array($sms->cid,$sms->mid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using  xml_parse_into_struct() you can convert XML to array, for detailed document check below link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php